# it’s just as comfortable with a remake

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from [a *The Atlantic* article](https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2022/02/gun-safety-hollywood-alec-baldwin/622836/).

> “As long as you’re going to have real guns on movie sets,” she said,
> “there is going to be this problem.” In other words, Hollywood may
> like a happy ending, but **it’s just as comfortable with a remake**.

What does the sentence in bold mean in the above context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your level of familiarity with English idiom, so I will explain this as though you are from another culture and not familiar at all.

First the simple meaning of the terms.

Hollywood is an area in Los Angeles California. It is famous for having many movie studios and producing many movies that are important to the culture in the US.

A "happy ending" is a story that ends with the hero and the people he or she cares about being happy. Maybe they had horrible problems in the middle of the story. But by the end of the story, the problems are all solved, and the heroes of the story are all safe and happy.  In the movie Oz, Dorothy is home from Oz, and she is safe with her whole family. In the moive Jaws, the shark is dead and Chief Brody and Matt Hooper are swimming back to shore. The crew of Apollo 13 make it back to Earth safely. These are the endings that Hollywood feels comfortable with.

A recent movie that does *not* have a happy ending is “Don’t Look Up.” I won’t give more spoilers but recall that the main idea of the movie is that a huge asteroid is coming to smash into the Earth.

Hollywood is also famous for making remakes of movies that were previously successful.  A remake is a movie with basically the same story as a previous movie. [There are many such examples.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_film_remakes)  The idea seems to be that a previous idea that worked will work again.    Sometimes the remake makes money, sometimes not.

Now the quote. What it is saying is, Hollywood likes things to work out nice in the end. They don’t like the fact that people got shot during the making of this movie. Hollywood wants everybody to go home safe and be happy.  BUT! But Hollywood likes making money. And if they think doing what they did before will make them money, then they will do what they did before.

So, Hollywood wants everybody to go home safe from making a movie, but when it comes down to it, they care more about making money. So, they will probably not make big drastic changes to keep real guns off movie sets or to make people more likely to use them safely.

Comment: Thank you very much